# Determine no. of records returned by Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

How do we know the no. of records returned by jquery ui autocomplete? I need to perform some client side logic when autocomplete doesn't return any data(when no match found). How do I know whether autocomplete returns data or not(when no match found)?

Regards
Sarayu

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
   $('#fieldId').autocomplete('AjaxHandler.ashx', {
       dataType: "json",
       parse: function(data) {
         var array = new Array();
         if (!data || data.length == 0) {
             // handle 
         }
     }
```

Return data as json using [newton json serializer](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) at yours Handler:

```
List<DataItem> items = GetDataItems();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
```

Comment: But I am using a web handler(ashx) to return the data. In that case, how will I need to habdle?